# Как переопределить скрипт?

Tags: javascript, email, form

Привет есть скрипт отправки формы

```
$("#openform").submit(function() { //Change
    var th = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: path/js/mail.php", //Change
        data: th.serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        $('#openform')[0].reset();
        alert('Ваша заявка отправлена.')
    });
    return false;

});
```

Как задать условие что если не все гладко вывести alert( на данный момент в коносоль показывает ошибку, к примеру если не все поля заполнены)

Comment: А что должно быть гладко?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#openform").submit(function() { //Change
    var th = $(this);

    if (th.email) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: path/js/mail.php", //Change
            data: th.serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            $('#openform')[0].reset();
            alert('Ваша заявка отправлена.')
        });
    } else {
         alert('Вы не заполнили поле E-MAIL');
         return false;
    }
});
```